# Launch Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated) and run SSIS package using Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, shell, visual-studio-2012, ssis, scheduler

I am working on a project that creates a reporting database by loading data from an AS400 into SQL Server 2012 Express (just FYI - I do not have sql agent or sql profiler). I downloaded sql server data tools with the SSIS designer and created a couple of data loading packages within the same solution. I have researched running SSIS packages using the DTExec utility, and for the most part it worked fine, however, I was not able to log any of the runtime data to a log table (only the text file log worked), and for some reason the send emails tasks didn't send emails when run through DTExec. Both of these things worked fine when running the packages directly in VS Shell.

While trying to troubleshoot these issues, I realized that I do not actually have integration services installed on my machine - just the designer. I will not be able to get integration services (soon, at least) so I would like to figure out how to launch VS Shell, validate, build and execute my SSIS load packages - not using the DTExec utility, but actually launching in the VS Shell using Windows Scheduler.

I know that to launch the program itself, I would just schedule devenv.exe. But what arguments do I use to validate, build and execute the packages using this method. The only thing I can find about executing packages involves using the utility, and assumes that the user has SSIS installed, not just the designer.

Now, if worse comes to worse I can just execute the load packages and then create some sql queries to pull together the row counts and other stuff I will need to audit the data, but it seems like there should be a way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to launch VS using the windows scheduler:

1. create a task
2. go to actions, edit
3. In the program/script box enter the path to devenv.exe (using double quotes) - *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"*
4. In Add arguments enter *devenv /runexit /project [project name] "\fileserver\path[solution name].sln"*

You can use other switches for arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

The only thing is that because it is running in visual studio (at least for me) is that it runs in debug mode, so you have to click stop to stop debugging. So in my case, I used the runexit switch, which is supposed to close VS when the package is complete. It only closed after I clicked stop. I tried using the /command switch to execute a stop debugging command (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx) *Debug.StopDebugging*, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason you're not able to run an SSIS package outside of BIDS/SSDT/Visual Studio and it's called licensing.

With the 2012 release of SQL Server, you're free to develop SSIS packages to your heart's content. However, to get them to run outside of Visual Studio means you need to have installed SQL Server on the invoking machine. Even though it's "just integration services", that's a SQL Server installation and thus a license is required. A developer edition license of SQL Server is cheap: ~50 USD per user. However, since it *sounds* like you're making a "productionalized" version, you're going to need a Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition, depending on the features used in SSIS. SE or EE is not cheap and with the change to licensing with the 2012 release (per core vs per socket), it's gotten more precious.

You're looking for a technical solution and if you find one, you're likely going to be in violation of licensing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The solution I am looking for is not to run the package outside of Visual Studio - I would like to figure out an automatic way to open Visual Studio and run the package. So basically, instead of double clicking VS, opening the package a clicking run, I want to schedule Windows to open VS and execute the package. It doesn't sound to me like this would be a violation of any kind licensing - I'll have to go back over the SSDT licensing terms.

Comment: I do realize that the spirit of what I am trying to do could be in violation of the terms. I'll have to do some more research into the terms before I role this out. Otherwise, I do have another software I could use for the data integration portion of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoIT to script GUI applications:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 0):

I used the run flag in task scheduler and I was able to get the the debugger to automatically stop by taking advantage of user32.dll via a script. Basically I send the close command message and a button click to the ok on the close dialog. Below is my cookie cutter task I put at the end of my projects... If you just want to stop without exit you could probably just send shift+f5 too.

```
private static string project = "MyProjectName";

    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    private const int BN_CLICKED = 245;

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
    /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
    /// To open Help, press F1.
    /// </summary>
    public void Main()
    {
        int hwndChild = 0;
        int hWnd = FindWindow(null, project + " (Running) - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)");

        if (hWnd == 0)
            hWnd = FindWindow(null, project + " (Running) - Microsoft Visual Studio");

        if (hWnd == 0)
            hWnd = FindWindow(null, project + " - Microsoft Visual Studio");

        if (hWnd > 0)
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            while (hwndChild == 0)
            {
                hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Visual Studio");

                hwndChild = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Yes");
                if (hwndChild == 0)
                    hwndChild = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Yes");

                SendMessage(hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```